# how do media queries determine the device resolution?

Tags: media-queries, resolution, user-agent

I was wondering how media queries determine the device resolution. Is there a way to affect the way media queries respond with a custom user agent?

Thanks, Charlie

Comment: From what I understand, media queries do very simple and basic checks based on the parameters you give it, and the qualities of the browser, not the user agent. If you want to do things based on user agent, you may need to use Javasxript.

Comment: Right, but what I'm interested in knowing is how the media query determines the browser is displaying at 192 dpi versus 120 dpi. How does it obtain that information and can it be masked with a custom user agent?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact process media queries work, and, surprisingly, a Google search did not return anything very useful. I would really doubt though, that it can be 'masked' as you put it. But, I could be wrong, and likely someone will post right after this telling me why. ;)

Comment: BTW, can you share what you are trying to do. Perhaps there is another solution.

Comment: I have a 1X resolution browser: http://blindbrowser.com

I am attempting to have it mask itself to pull in 1X resolution media queries.

Comment: Right now, it displays the all elements in 1X, but I want it to respect lower resolution queries as well, so users can truly experience it as it would be on a 1X machine.

Comment: Have you tried using a 'lower resolution' query to check that it is indeed different than on your Retina?

Comment: yes, i used: http://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WebKit, this is implemented in [MediaQueryEvaluator.cpp](http://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-955.66/css/MediaQueryEvaluator.cpp).